# The Chinese Remainder Theorem with exponentials

Tags: discrete-mathematics, chinese-remainder-theorem

Find all $k∈Z_+$ such that:

i) $7834^k≡1$ $(mod$ $8613)$

ii) $7834^k≡6850$ $(mod$ $8613)$

iii) $7834^k≡2703$ $(mod$ $8613)$

iv) $7834^k≡1318$ $(mod$ $8613)$

Where $8613=3^3 *11 *29$

Hi I'm trying to learn the Chinese Remainder Theorem and now I'm facing problem where I have to it for exponentials. I have been given a proper solution, I just have a hard time following.

The solution:

We have isomorfi $f: Z_{8613} → (Z_{27}$ x $Z_{11}$ x $Z_{29})$. The I get $f(7834)=(4,2,4), f(1)=(1,1,1), f(6850)=(19,8,6), f(2703)=(3,8,6)$ and  $f(1318)=(22,9,13)$.

So far so good, now the solution looks at a table:

[image]

Now apparently I'm supposed to be able to deduce that:

For part i) is says: $k≡_9 0,≡_{10} 0, ≡_{14} 0$

ii) $k≡_9 6, ≡_{10} 3, ≡_{14} 3$

iii) Is no such $k$ such that $4^k = 3$ in $Z_{27}$.

iv) $k≡_9 7, ≡_{10} 6, ≡_{14} 9$

Can someone please explain the last step after the table and how do I go from there to answer what $k$ is? Thanks.

Comment: I think this is a mod equation., for a) i have got $$k=630m$$ where $m$ is an integer number.

Comment: That is true, but how do you conclude that?

Comment: i have git it by squaring

Comment: What do you mean? How do I go from $k≡_9 0,≡_{10} 0, ≡_{14} 0$ to $k=630m$?

Comment: I mean $$7834^2\equiv 391\mod 8613$$, $$7834^4\equiv 1039\mod 8613$$,$$7834^8\equiv 2896\mod 8613$$ and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do case $(ii)$ below (the others are very similar).

$\begin{align}  
\phantom{\iff}&\qquad7834^k \equiv\ 6850\ \ \ \ \ \,\pmod{27\cdot 11\cdot 29}\\[.2em]
\iff&\ \ \  (4,2,4)^k\equiv (19,8,6)\pmod{27,\ 11,\ 29}\\[.2em]
\iff& \left\{\begin{array}{}4^k\equiv 19\pmod{27}\iff k\equiv 6\pmod{9}\\
                           2^k\equiv\ \ 8\pmod{11}\iff k\equiv 3\pmod{10}\\
                           4^k\equiv\ \ 6\pmod{29} \iff k\equiv 3\pmod{14}
                         \end{array}\right.
\end{align}$

Now $\,10,14\mid k-3\iff 70\mid k-3,\ $ by $\,{\rm lcm}(10,14) = 2\,{\rm lcm}(5,7)=70$

So $\,\bmod \color{#0a0}9\!:\,\ 6\equiv k\equiv 3+70\,\color{#c00}n\equiv 3-2n\iff 2n\equiv 6\iff \color{#c00}{n\equiv 3}$

Thus we conclude $\, k = 3+70(\color{#c00}3+\color{#0a0}9k) = 213+ 630k $

Comment: How do you go from $4^k≡19 (mod$ $27)$ to $k≡6 (mod$ $9)$. I don't follow that step.

Comment: @BLCAAN That info is in your table of powers: it shows $\large \bmod 27\!:\ 4^{\Large 6}\equiv 19,\,\ 4^{\Large 9}\equiv 1\ $

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but I need a little more help on the last congruence. for part iv) I get that:

$k ≡ 7$ $(mod$ $9)$,

$k ≡ 6$ $(mod$ $10)$,

$k ≡ 9$ $(mod$ $14)$.

Since $gcd(10,14)=2$ I need that:

$6 ≡ 9$ $(mod$ $2)$ however that is not true and hence it should be no solution. Is that right?

Comment: @BLCAAN Right, said equivalently if a solution $k$ existed then it would yield a *parity* contradiction $\,k = 6\!+\!10i\,\Rightarrow\, k\,$ even, but $\,k= 9+14j\,\Rightarrow\, k$ odd. **Or:** $\ 10i\!-\!14j=9\!-\!6\,\Rightarrow\,\gcd(10,14)\mid 9\!-\!6,\,$ i.e. $\,2\mid 3,\,$ contradiction (that's how the proof of the solvability condition works in general).